# Understanding multiple inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions

I'm trying to use multiple inheritance to solve a complex hierarchy that I'm developing. The situation is the following:

```
class A {
  virtual void foo();
}

class B {
  virtual void foo();
}

class C : public B {

}

class D : public A, public C {
  void foo() { ... }
}

class ClientClass {
  void method() {
    A *a = new D();
    a->foo();
  }
```

What I wonder is: will `D` have just one function `foo()` in the end? I'm thinking about it because the method is virtual in both parents so they should like collimate onto the same one, but I thin this just because I come from Java and I feel that it may be different in C++. I have to declare the virtual function `foo()` twice because `ClientClass` doesn't know `B` or `C` but just `A`. This is a requirement I would like to keep.

EDIT: does the same answer apply even if both `foo()` in `A` and `B` are pure virtual? (eg `= 0`)

Comment: I've only fiddled with multiple inheritance a little bit, so I can't really answer your question. I will warn you, though, that there are a large number of programmers who consider any use of multiple inheritance to automatically be bad design.

Comment: @KRyan: I already know this but it's a my choice which will come handy in this specific situation.

Comment: can you describe why do you need this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the implementation of `D::foo` will override both `A::foo` and `B::foo` at the same time.

Both inherited functions will still be available, of course, to be called by their full name. But that's not different than in the single inheritance case.

About the `ClientClass`, you create a `D` object and then call `foo` through a pointer to `A`. So the `D::foo` override will be called.

If you want different versions of `foo` for the override of `A::foo` and `C::foo` (for example, because they are unrelated but happen to be called the same way) then you will need a bit of work:

```
class A2 : public A
{
public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        A_foo();
    }
    virtual void A_foo()
    {
        A::foo();
    }
};
class C2 : public C
{
public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        C_foo();
    }
    virtual void C_foo()
    {
        C::foo();
    }
};
class  D: public A2, C2
{
public:
    virtual void A_foo()
    { /* ... */ }
    virtual void C_foo()
    { /* ... */ }
};
```

Now the use:

```
{
    A *a = new D;
    a->foo(); //will call A2::foo -> D::A_foo
    B *b = new D;
    b->foo(); //will call C2::foo -> D::C_foo
    D *d = new D;
    d->foo(); //error: ambiguous call!
}
```

Comment: Actually I made a mistake, the ClientClass declares an `A` but uses instantiates `D` (actually it is set from outside ClientClass). So the effective implementation will be just one and both name will clash onto the same name? Must I declare the `foo()` method pure virtual for this to happen?

Comment: @Jack: Ok, now it is clear. It will call `D::foo`, of course. The pure-ness of the function has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

D will have two.  They can be accessed with `A :: foo()` and `B :: foo()` inside the class.

Comment: But will they share the same implementation under all circumstances? In the sense that it is safe to implement `foo()` just in the child of both classes and at the same time make the method available either to who just know A or C

Comment: Very good question.  It doesn't _usually_ make much sense.  This is a headache of a problem, which leads to redesigning base classes with virtual inheritance listed in other answers.  You should carefully think through the design that led you here.

Answer (score 2):

The class `D` has three functions `foo`: `D::foo`, `B::foo` and `A::foo`.

Since `foo` is virtual in both `A` and `B`, an unqualified function call is dispatched dynamically to the most derived function:

```
void f(A & a) { a.foo(); }
void g(B & b) { b.foo(); }

int main()
{
    D d;
    f(d);       // calls d.D::foo();
    g(d);       // calls d.D::foo();

    d.foo();    // calls d.D::foo();
    d.B::foo(); // calls d.B::foo();
    d.A::foo(); // calls d.A::foo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have hit a classical issue with multiple inheritance, possibly the most important one suggesting for a very limited use of it (through the concept of mixins or interfaces/virtual classes).

Have a look at [this post from S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380529/multiple-inheritance?rq=1) for a fuller explanation and various alternatives you have.

Comment: There is no diamond inheritance here, or at least there is no common ancestor. Just two methods with the same name, what I was wondering is that it was considered diamond inheritance in this situation too.

Comment: it's not the infamous diamond relationship, but just the same method names in different base classes, therefore virtual inheritance won't be of any use! But the link is good :D

Comment: Reviewing the design may reveal the need for virtual inheritance which would cause the diamond relationship, which has these issues.

Answer (score 0):

In this code :

```
class ClientClass {
  void method() {
    A *a = new D();
    a->foo();
  }
```

D's foo will run. And you can still access A foo with a->A::foo().
Notice that the way you initialized 'a' you can't reach B foo().
But each time you'll build a D instance it will uses the D foo, as both of the foo function are declared virtual.

For each class in your code you have a table of functions.
The table for each object is defined by it's **type**. That means the `A * a = new D()` has the A table of function. 
If a function has a virtual flag before it that means that if an instance of a derived class is build, it's table will contain a pointer to the function of the derived class.

Which means in your code in the ClinetClass the The 'a' object has the A function table, where it's foo function containing a pointer to the D foo function.

Just to note that in case D did not have it own foo and you would write

```
D * d =  new D();
d-> foo();
```

You would get a compile error has he does not know which foo function he should use.